# Can this code throw any other exception than ConcurrentModificationException?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, integer

I was wondering if there was any other exception this piece of code may throw.

```
public class asd{
static private List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
public static main(String[]args){
list.add(0);
list.add(1);
list.add(3);
for(Integer integer: list) {
        if(integer% 2 == 0) {
           list.remove(integer); 
        }
    }
  }
}
```

I know about the ConcurrentModificationException. I'm only wondering whether this piece of code is capable of doing any more mess. Thanks alot

Comment: Please post a practical proof of concept, instead of a hardcoded example with perfectly predictable outcome. I mean, if you can predict the outcome at *compile-time*, there's no need for exceptions at all (unless it's a mental exercise).

Answer (score 2):

This specific code doesn't throw an exception because the list is empty. 
But there can be `NullPointerException`s, if there are `null` values in the list. (Unboxing: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

Answer (score 0):

No, furthermore the loop will not be executed as there are no elements in the `list`, but if there were some, only the `ConcurrentModificationException` would be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Your code as written is entirely deterministic: It does the same thing where-ever you run it. Thus, which exceptions does it throw? Well, run it. That's what it'll throw, and it won't throw anything else. As others have said, this code in particular will throw `ConcurrentModificationException`, because if you want to in-line remove, you need to use the iterators `remove()` method (and you can't access that method if you're using `for( a : b)` style, you have to go with `Iterator<T> it = list.iterator(); while (it.next()) { .. }` instead.

If you want a general deep dive on what exceptions can occur in java apps, well, one could write whole books on that topic. I guess to just name some random stuff that comes to mind, looking at that code:

if the list is heap corrupted, the silent cast to an integer would throw `ClassCastException`. If there are nulls in the list, the autounbox would throw `NullPointerException`. If you'd had forgotten to initialize the list, that would have thrown a `NullPointerException`, or the compiler would fail with the error 'list not initialized', depending on how you wrote your code.

Answer (score 0):

Only **ConcurrentModificationException** would be thrown as list element is empty after executing list.remove(integer).